# Will releasing an iPhone app makes it available for iPad by default?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In my XCode's Targets summary screen, the "Devices" drop down is set to "iPhone" (other possible values are iPad and Universal) because I haven't fine tuned the app's UI for iPad. However, will people be able to download and run my app from the iPad in non-fullscreen? (e.g., with black border surrounding most of the screen)

I want people to be able to search for it in app store, install it, and run it even though it is not full screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though your device settings for app is iPhone, you can download it from iPad, but it can be viewed only as in iphone size or  in `2x` option is there on right bottom side of the app (refer image) to double the app size in ipad; but doubled view will look stretched.
An iphone app downloaded to ipad will look like as shown (In 1x mode).

[image: (In 1x mode)]

Comment: mvp is right. if you open the app store and navigate to your bought apps, you can seperate them between iPad and iPhone on top in the right corner. all iPhone apps can't start in fullscreen and will apear like mvp has shown.

Comment: cool! It's great to know that without doing anything ipad users will also be able to use it, albeit not in full screen :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's on the app store as an iPhone app then you can still run it on the iPad but they'll run in their original size unless you change the size to fit using the 1x or 2x icon. The graphics won't be as sharp and if your app uses any iPhone only features - make calls, then it's not going to work as expected.

If you want to get rid of the little iPhone app inside the iPad then you'll need to change the target to Universal in order to run as a native iPad app

Comment: You'll need to do more than just change the target

Answer (score -2):

What type build you use? XIB or Storyboard?

In any case go to the drop down menu and set Universal App, xcode create automatically the Xib or storyboard target for iPad, and the app run in full screen on iPad.

Ok now you have to setting up a new interface specific fo iPad:

if you use a xib files, you have to only resize the interface target for iPad.

if you use a Storyboard, in order you have to

1. Right click on your project and click on NewFile
2. add New Storyboard target fon iPad

Now you have a new storyboard for ipad, but is empty and not linked, so go to you project setting and set the new story under the iPad settings, click on iPhone Storyboard and pres `CMD + A` select all inside your storyboard for iPhone go to your storyboard for iPad and again `CMD + A` and press `CANC` Yes delete all inside a iPad Storyboard and press `CMD + V` now you have copy all your project correctly target for ipad but now you need to relink and resize all stuff.

Hope this help you and other people, do not forget vote up ;)

Comment: You scared me? they edit and change the question the first question are different before edit, is a new user ask how can become a universal App. in fact i get one vote for the user post question! so now regive me my point dude